# sfGuardAuth signin form i18n translation

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I am having difficulties with properly translating the `sfGuardAuth` signin form without "breaking it down". In the built-in template the form is rendered like this:

```php
<?php echo $form ?>
```

And I would like to keep it that way.

When the default culture is set to Polish the results look like this:

[image: Login form]

Only the "Password" is translated to "Hasło", the rest remains in English. Making new custom translation file - `sf_guard.pl.xml` or editing the base one directly in the plugin folder by adding:

```
<trans-unit id="32">
  <source>Username or E-Mail</source>
  <source>Nazwa użytkownika lub E-Mail</source>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="33">
  <source>Remember</source>
  <source>Zapamiętaj mnie</source>
</trans-unit>
```

Doesn't have any effect. Is there a way to translate those fields without rewriting the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change tags in this way (and then clear the cache):

```
<trans-unit id="32">
  <source>Username or E-Mail</source>
  <target>Nazwa użytkownika lub E-Mail</target>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="33">
  <source>Remember</source>
  <target>Zapamiętaj mnie</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Comment: Oh wow, how didn't I notice that? Copied straight from the original translation file - which now I see has this bug in the last three trans-units. I guess that's a LFMF question now. Thanks